# MonoDevelop (Unity built-in) no longer auto-completing anything

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I'm having some serious issues with MonoDevelop and Unity. I use unity on both my (Windows) laptop, and on my PC, carrying one project between the two on a flash drive. Recently, however, MonoDevelop has decided to stop auto-completing things that I type. It started on my laptop, and then weeks later became a problem on my PC. It's not just the Unity compatibility that's gone; it does not auto-complete at all.

I have tried to use Visual Studio, following a [tutorial by Brackeys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2PVPz8Pnnrw), but couldn't get that to work at all (it threw up errors even at the `#pragma strict` line). I have searched around for anything that could help, and while I found many topics on both of these problems, none of them ended up working. Besides the things I found online, I have also reinstalled Unity, Visual Studio, and UnityVS several times, to no avail.

Hopefully this also helps anyone else who is encountering the same problem.

Note: I am developing my project purely in JavaScript. While I know a bit of C#, I am not comfortable using it for this.

Comment: Can't speak for MonoDevelop sadly as I tend to use Visual Studio but these sorts of problems can often be solved by clearing the autocomplete database. For MonoDevelop it looks like these should .pidb files stored in your UnityProj (needless to say worth backing up before attempting this just in case)

Comment: Ok, that's great! Thanks for the input. I will try that soon (can't right now). However, would you mind briefly telling me what you did to use VS alongside unity?

Comment: UnityVS - that's pretty much it :P Should be an installer which gives you a Custom Package to include in your Unity Project. Off the top of my head that;s about it - it got a lot easier when Microsoft acquired UnityVS and easier still when Unity started bundling VS and UnityVS with Unity5, it largely just works for me now.

If you're having issues with that it might be worth opening a new question and linking it?

Comment: Alright, I have tried clearing the database, but sadly that did not work. However, I did discover that the problem is only with javascript. When using js, no autocompletion is available (not even stock js stuff) but in a c# script, it seems to work fine. Furthermore, I tried it in the unity sample project, and the same thing happened. I have yet to try what you said with VS, but I think that was something that I read about and tried before creating this thread (We shall see though).

Comment: Unfortunately, UnityVS did not work either. I installed it, grabbed the package and imported into unity, and then opened up Visual Studio, but no luck. It still seems to be treating it somewhat like C# code (e.x. "#pragma strict" still comes up as an error. I also tried restarting my computer, for the heck of it. No luck. I'm out of time now, but I will create a thread about the issue with UnityVS and link it here. Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582707/unable-to-set-up-unityvs-visual-studio-tools-for-unity) is the link to the other thread I just made, regarding not being able to get UnityVS to work.

Comment: It seems many are getting issue with autocompletion. Unity probably did something wrong lately. It does go on and off with me as well but the answer I gave is fixing it for me temporarily. Nonetheless, just so you know, there is another question related to yours that came up a few hours after yours, you are not alone.

Comment: Alright, well, thank you, both of you, for your help. :) Hopefully this helps someone else, if not me.

Answer (score -1):

I found alternative to this

First install **Sublime Text**

in Sublime Text go to Preferences > Settings - More > Syntax Specific - User

Open the root of your Unity project in Sublime. There should be a .sln file there.
Save your Sublime project there. Project > Save Project As

Add

```
{
"folders":
[
{
"follow_symlinks": true,
"path": "."
}
],
"solution_file": "./ProjectName.sln"
}
```

Change *ProjectName.sln* with your project name

In Unity set Preferences > External Tools > External Script Editor to **Sublime Text**

[check this](http://makegamessa.com/discussion/2879/tutorial-using-sublime-text-3-in-unity-with-intellisense-autocomplete)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.