# Unable to set up UnityVS/Visual Studio tools for Unity

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015, integration, unityvs

I am running Visual Studio 2015 and Unity 5.3.1f1.

No matter what I do, the toolbar does not appear. VS throws an error at the `#pragma strict` line at the beginning of the code.

I've followed these steps:

- installed `UnityVS`
- found the unity package file and imported it into my project.

I did read somewhere that in newer versions, the toolbar isn't there.

Although intellisense works, it does not seem to be capable of auto-completing anything to do with unity (e.x. `transform.position`)

How to fix?

Answer (score 1):

UnityScript is no longer supported (since 1.9 in Visual Studio Tools for Unity), only c#.

> we removed our basic support for UnityScript and Boo to better focus on the C# experience
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn940028.aspx#Anchor_6

Comment: Ah. That's interesting. Wonder if I could just backdate to 2013 or something?